# How to limit search radius to a rectangular area in a url query string

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, radius

I am using a web scraper in a Node.js project to pull results from a website and am trying to get the results from only a specific radius (like a five-block latitude and three-block longitude radius).  It does not seem to work with the URL query strings for latitude and longitude as it seems that these are only used for designating a specific point and not a radius.

Is there a way to query my results in a radius that is available in npm?  Not sure adding a google maps API will work here since I am scraping results.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you give examples that include a sample URL and the queries?

Comment: I did find that a possible solution is using north,south,east,west coordinates in the URL query string and it seems to have provided results within the radius.

Comment: I seem to have found a workaround and it is now populating in that area, it shows.  But the URL on chromium is still showing up with the LatitudeMax and LongitudeMin in the URL.

Is what I am doing in the URL query acceptable?

Comment: Hi sudo_kaizen - thanks for trying to help.

I am using puppeteer with the following URL  in async/await:

  let url =
    "https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=14&Center=43.771556%2C-79.427630&north=43.48&east=-79.23&west=79.26&south=-43.42&view=list&CurrentPage=1&Sort=6-D&PGeoIds=g10_dpz90869&GeoName=Vancouver%2C%20British+Columbia%2C%20ON&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PriceMax=1500000&BuildingTypeId=1&Currency=CAD";

Comment: Previous URL query:

let url =
    "https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=14&Center=43.771556%2C-79.427630&LatitudeMax=43.78395&LongitudeMax=-79.38710&LatitudeMin=43.75916&LongitudeMin=-79.46816&view=list&CurrentPage=1&Sort=6-D&PGeoIds=g10_dpz90869&GeoName=Vancouver%2C%20British+Columbia%2C%20ON&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PriceMax=1500000&BuildingTypeId=1&Currency=CAD";

Comment: If you are scraping the results, I think you should visit a URL on the site (by navigating the site to where you can get the type of information you want ) and then copy the URL that presents you with that information; then modify the exact parameters in your code to give you the dynamic results you want.

Comment: You could change the parameters in the URL in your browser to see the result to make sure what you're getting from puppeteer is what you're getting from the browser